# Swift MacOS - Is there a way to block access(stop focus) to background apps when my app is opened?

Tags: swift, macos, focus

I'm fairly new to Mac Development and now I'm developing a Swift application for desktop. The application consist of a window, which has a webview in it. Is there any possiblity that when my window opens it always stays at top, and you cannot click on any other windows bellow it.

For now I have made it this far with my code:

```
func applicationWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    NSApplication.shared().activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
}


func applicationDidResignActive(_ notification: Notification) {
    NSApplication.shared().activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
}
```

I'm using  **applicationWillHide** and **applicationDidResignActive** to bring the window back to the top when a user clicks outside of it, but its still possible to focus on background apps, although they are not at the top. Can this "stealing" of focus somehow be disabled?

Comment: I hope no. It could be turned into malware otherwise

Comment: Always on top - yes, block access to other process windows - no. Why would you want to do this?